# Loading huggingface dataset with load_dataset() from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, huggingface-datasets, fsspec

I need to modify existing code to be able to use the huggingface `load_dataset()` function. It currently works on local files, but I need to migrate the dataset to an Azure blob storage and be able to load from there. I'm confused as of how to do this.

The [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/filesystems#load-and-save-your-datasets-using-your-cloud-storage-filesystem) does mention having support via fsspec, but it doesn't show what to do with the fs variable once I have it. So basically I'm doing:

```
storage_options = {"anon": True}
storage_options = {"account_name": ACCOUNT_NAME, "account_key": ACCOUNT_KEY}
storage_options={"tenant_id": TENANT_ID, "client_id": CLIENT_ID, "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET}

import adlfs
fs = adlfs.AzureBlobFileSystem(**storage_options)
```

But what next? Do I just do `load_dataset(fs)`? Can I pass the fs object instead of a path? Or how do I actually load the dataset from the blob storage with load_dataset?

UPDATE:

I'm doing:

```
from datasets import load_dataset, load_from_disk  
storage_options = {"connection_string": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=acname;AccountKey=key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"} 
data = load_dataset("abfs://ctnr-invoices", storage_options=storage_options)
```

This still tries to find files locally, as I can see via the error message: `FileNotFoundError: Couldn't find a dataset script at C:\Users\me\Documents\abfs:\ctnr-invoices\ctnr-invoices.py or any data file in the same directory.` I haven't found documentation about "az://".

Comment: Are you okay with the `from in memory data` approach ? https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v1.2.1/loading_datasets.html#from-in-memory-data for getting data Azure blob storage.

Comment: @Venkatesan ideally I'd use load_dataset because that way I don't have to modify the code in 5 separate places, but if that won't work I'll have to do it some other way...

Comment: Using `load_dataset` it is not possible but `from datasets import Dataset` it is possible.

Comment: @Venkatesan wdym it's not possible? The documentation specifically mentions load_dataset cloud compatibility, I  just can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: As an alternate approach, I have used this code able to fetch the dataset. https://i.imgur.com/J6Ujapn.png. is it okay?

Comment: @Venkatesan, no, the dataset is not a csv. It's a mixture of image files and a metadata.jsonl.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256123/discussion-between-venkatesan-and-lte).

Answer (score -1):

The docstring for `load_dataset` includes:

```
    storage_options (`dict`, *optional*, defaults to `None`):
        **Experimental**. Key/value pairs to be passed on to the dataset file-system backend, if any.
```

(datasets = 2.14.6)

So, you need to use options like the ones you are trying (with correct credentials), making sure that the paths begin "az://".

The `fs` object is a filesystem instance, allowing you to list/find files inside containers and get their information, perform operations (copy, delete...) and open file-like objects. I believe HF is doing this internally, so for just loading, you shouldn't need it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be as simple. I'm doing: 
`from datasets import load_dataset, load_from_disk

storage_options = {"connection_string": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=acname;AccountKey=key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"}
data = load_dataset("abfs://ctnr-invoices", storage_options=storage_options)`


This still tries to find files locally, as I can see via the error message: `FileNotFoundError: Couldn't find a dataset script at C:\Users\me\Documents\abfs:\ctnr-invoices\ctnr-invoices.py or any data file in the same directory.`

I haven't found documentation about "az://"

Comment: You should put this into your original question

Comment: done, added it to the post